# Negative integers and polynomial congruence classes

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's take a polynomial $m(x)$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$. Now, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ should contains the integers $-1,-2,-3$. However after reading few exercises about this argument i suspect that we can ignore negative values when we work modulo $m(x)$. But, why ? (Intuitively)

Comment: What is your definition of $\,\Bbb Z_3[x]?\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z_3=\{[0],[1],[2]\}$ where $$[n]=\{n+3k|k\in\mathbb Z\}$$
which means that $[-3]=[0], [-2]=[1]$ and $[-1]=[2]$.

Comment: What i don't understand is why the polynomials with negative coefficients are equal to ones with positive coefficients ...

Comment: @AleQuercia Because there is no such thing as "negative" and "positive" in $\mathbb Z_3$. The *number* $-2$ is not an element of $\mathbb Z_3$. The **equivalence class** of this number is an element. And this class contains both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: @5xum Keep in mind that many ENT textbooks use only congruences, not quotient rings.

Comment: I think that what you wrote derives from the fact that when working with polynomials modulo negative coefficients are equivalent to positive ones